# Merge two shorted linked list

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have an error in logic, I was trying to do merging using recursion .please guide me where I am wrong.

Input (stdin):

4

1 3 5 6

3

2 4 7

My Output (stdout):
1 3 5 6

Expected Output: 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7

```
 /*
  Node is defined as 
  class Node {
     int data;
     Node next;
  }
*/

Node mergeLists(Node headA, Node headB) {
    if(headA==null)
    {
        return headB;
    }
    if(headB==null)
    {
        return headA;
    }
    if(headA.data<headB.data)
    {  
        headA.next=mergeLists(headA.next,headB.next);
        return headA;
    }
    else{

        headB.next=mergeLists(headA.next,headB.next);
        return headB;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's time to learn to use a debugger to debug your own code. If you still can't figure it out with a debugger, please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are advancing both lists where you should only advance in one of them.

```
Node mergeLists(Node headA, Node headB) {
    if(headA==null)
    {
        return headB;
    }
    if(headB==null)
    {
        return headA;
    }
    if(headA.data<headB.data)
    {  
        headA.next=mergeLists(headA.next,headB); // Note change here, using only smallest
        return headA;
    }
    else{

        headB.next=mergeLists(headA,headB.next); // Note change here, using only smallest
        return headB;
    }
}
```